# socket undefined inside of socket.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have the current code;

```
socket.on('KeyPress', function(data){
    var ply = PLAYER_LIST[socket.id];
    /* ... */
 });
```

WebStorm is informing me that socket.id may not be initialized, and then when this event is triggered it does cause the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

The whole code is inside of

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ /*...*/ });
```

Here is two of the on method I'm using;
[image]
In the first block you can see I'm doing the same thing yet it works..

Also on that note how secure is it to use socket.id to auth a user? Is it possible to force-set your own id?

Comment: Please do NOT ever post code as images.  Post code as text and then we can copy/paste to show you corrections to your code without having to manually retype things.  Plus you never get the benefit of search indexing on images either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a victim of a bad practice of defining variables with `var` within a loop and then getting bit by the influence of "variable hoisting" where a variable defined with `var` anywhere in the function is automatically declared at the start of the function and then initialized where your assignment was, meaning it's `undefined` everywhere in your function before that.

The problem is this line of code:

```
var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
```

That is redefining a local variable named `socket` that hides the one you actually want.  Variables defined with `var` are function scoped.  That means they are defined at the top of the function (this is called variable hoisting) and thus hides the other parent scoped `socket` variable.

Think of your function as starting like this:

```
socket.on('KeyPress', function(data) {
    var socket;       // this is hoisted from deeper inside the function
                      // and creates a new undefined socket variable
    var ply = PLAYER_LIST[socket.id];

    // other code here
});
```

This is essentially how Javascript sees your code.  You can do a search on "Javascript variable hoisting" and see LOTS of articles written on the topic if you want more info.

The smallest change you can make it to change the name of this local variable to something else to it doesn't interfere with the parent scoped variable, but really this code structure is not ideal in the first place.

```
var localSocket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
var ply = PLAYER_LIST[p];
localSocket.emit(...)
```

---

In general it's a bad practice to define a variable with `var` inside a `for` loop.  It leads to the "assumption" that it is scoped only to that loop, but in reality, it's scoped to the whole function and can mess with things outside of the loop.

In ES6, you can use `let` or `const` instead of `var` to declare a variable that is actually scoped to only the block of the loop.

Of other note, you should NEVER be iterating arrays with `for/in`.  That iterates all array properties (including other enumerable object properties), not just array elements.  ES6 adds `for/of` for iterating arrays this way.  In ES5, you can use the more traditional `for` loop or `.forEach()`.

Comment: @bloodless2010 - I would have included more of your code in my answer if I could copy/paste sections of it, but posting code in an image is a big obstacle to doing that.

Comment: wow! I can't believe I missed that I was totally unaware JavaScript worked this way, in my practice with other languages I assumed it was only in the loops scope. that clears up so much, thank you!